# Android System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Tags: android, runtime-error

```
....    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

done = true;
}

...


public class addcontacts extends ListActivity {

     protected void onCreate() {

     }
     protected void execute(final Boolean success) {
if (done) {
         adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
         setListAdapter(adapter);
}
     }

 }


public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

@Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

...

}
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

            setContentView(R.layout.main);


            ac = new addcontacts();
            ac.execute(true);


    }

...

public class getcontacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {


...
listItems.add(json_data.getString("login") + " " + derp);
...
}

...
}

 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        getc = null;
        //showProgress(false);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Runtime error:

```
 02-12 15:59:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1308): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 02-12 15:59:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1308): java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
 02-12 15:59:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1308):    at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:3989)

 02-12 15:59:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1308):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
 02-12 15:59:35.274: E/AndroidRuntime(1308):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Yes, it is not available. What is your question now?

Comment: Just do not access it too early?

Comment: No System services are available before Activity is fully constructed. i.e. call to onCreate() returns.

Comment: Where do you call `execute()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that is broken is your code. Fix would be to avoid access to system services prior onCreate() is completed otherwise there's no setup made yet to the activity object, hence the self-explaining-the-cause exception you facing.

Comment: addcontacts class is created 30 seconds after application is fully launched

Comment: **Your code is broken**. You cannot access system service unless `onCreate()` is completed. Period. Perhaps you got crappy device too or crappy device + lot of crap installed that make it sluggish but it makes not difference to how the framework works. You should better try to profile your app or try to find the culprit and fix it.

Comment: Android Virtual Device

Comment: Still, 30 seconds is a lot. It's not normal, even on AVD emulating tablet running JB

Comment: I just updated my first post. Added `done` variable. Code inside `if(done)` is executed, and that indicates that onCreate is done